# how to access aws ec2 tags

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to figure out the way to access AWS tag and then run some code on the instance with the tag.

How can I access the each key and value of the instance tags using AWS SDK for Ruby - Version 2?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'yaml'
Aws.config.update({
  region: region,
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV_YML['access_key_id'], ENV_YML['secret_access_key'])
})

ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new
ec2.instances.each do |instance|
  tags = instance.tags
  tags.each do |num|
    ### pseudo code
      puts tag owner # i want to get the value of tag owner
    if tag owner = "test" #then run on this tag if
      puts tag name #print the value of tag name
      #some code
    else 
      #some code
  end
end
```

when I do something like this :

```
ec2.instances.each do |instance|
  tags = instance.tags
  tags.each do |num|
  puts num
  end
end
```

The output is:

```
#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="Name", value="test.ec2.blabla.int">
```

But I want to be able to get only the value by calling the key(name) or whatever.

Please help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `facter` gem :

```
ec2.instances.each do |instance|
  tag_name = Facter::Util::Resolution.exec("ec2-describe-tags --region eu-west-1 --filter \"resource-id=#{instance.id}\" --filter key=Name | cut -f 5")
```

Answer (score 3):

The `instance.tags` returns an array of `Aws::EC2::Types::Tag` objects.
The documentation for that class is: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Types/Tag.html

The right way to access the value of a tag is by doing `tag.value` like this:

```rb
ec2.instances.each do |instance|
  tags = instance.tags
  tags.each do |tag|
    puts tag.value
  end
end
```

And if you want the value of a specific tag, let's say the Name tag, you can do it like this:

```rb
instance.tags.select{|tag| tag.key == "Name"}.first.try(:value)
```

It will return `nil` if the tag does not exists.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I got: 
NoMethodError: undefined method `try' for #<Aws::EC2::Types::Tag:0x007f84ac91f4a0>

The answer was to implement this: http://ozmm.org/posts/try.html

Comment: The page linked out by Jonathon Miller is 404ing. The way to do this now is instance.tags.select{|tag| tag.key == "Name"}.first.value